# APEX Tree region Escape Special Characters

Tags: tree, oracle-apex

I´m trying to make the text of the results in my tree bold, but only if they match a specific contidion, so in the sql query i tried this two option in the select statment :

'< div class="TFLBOLD">'||A.NAME||' - Nivel - '||level||'</ div>'

'< b>'||A.NAME||' - Nivel - '||level||'</ b>''

On the first one i was trying to create a class to assign bold style in the css page.

I already marked the option "Escape Special Characters" as "No" but it still doesn't put the text in bold and it looks like this:

[Tree image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3qoh4.png)

There is any problem or bug with this option on a Tree region Type?
There is another way to make text bold in my Tree region when the contidion is match?

Note: In reports regions the option works fine!

This a print from my tree code
[tree_code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YG4lX.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue, this is the answer from John Snyders:

Nodes can have icons and the icon can indicate different kinds of nodes.  This is the main purpose of the icon and the easiest way to differentiate between different types of branches in a tree. There is no declarative way to add a class to a node but it can be done using custom javascript.

Here is how to add a specific class to node content (using a typical tree on the EMP table). This is a general technique I use to get more info into the nodes than the Tree region supports. I put the extra data into the tooltip and then extract it when the tree is initialized.

In the tree region sql add a column to hold the desired classes. Example:

`case when job = 'SALESMAN' then 'sales' else '' end as node_class,`

For the Tooltip choose HTML Expression and enter:

`&NODE_CLASS.|Job: &JOB.<br> Salary: &SAL.`

Note that the tooltip contains the classes and the tooltip separated by a | character.

In the Advanced JavaScript Initialization Code enter:

```
function(options) { function traverse( n ) { var i, tta = n.tooltip ? n.tooltip.split("|") : [];

    if (tta.length === 3) {
        n.classes = tta[0];
        n.job = tta[1];
        n.tooltip = tta[2];
    }
    if ( n.children ) {
        for ( i = 0; i < n.children.length; i++ ) {
            traverse( n.children[i] );
        }
    }
}

options.makeNodeAdapter = function(data, types, hasIdentity) {
    var nodeAdapter;
    // split the classes out of the tooltip property
    traverse(data);
    nodeAdapter = $.apex.treeView.makeDefaultNodeAdapter( data, types, hasIdentity );
    nodeAdapter.renderNodeContent = function(node, out, options, state) {
        if ( options.nodeSelector > 0 ) {
            // simulate a checkbox or radio button depending on single/multiple selection
            cls = "u-selector"; // ++ replace constant
            if ( options.nodeSelector === 1 ) {
                cls += " u-selector--single";
            }
            out.markup('<span class="' + cls + '"></span>');
        }
        if ( nodeAdapter.getIcon ) {
            icon = nodeAdapter.getIcon( node );
            if ( icon !== null ) {
                out.markup( "<span" ).attr( "class", options.iconType + " " + icon ).markup( "></span>" );
            }
        }
        link = options.useLinks && nodeAdapter.getLink && nodeAdapter.getLink( node );
        if ( link ) {
            elementName = "a";
        } else {
            elementName = "span";
        }
        out.markup( "<" + elementName + " tabIndex='-1' role='treeitem'" ).attr( "class", options.labelClass )
            .optionalAttr( "href", link )
            .attr( "aria-level", state.level ) // ++ replace constant
            .attr( "aria-selected", state.selected ? "true" : "false" ) // ++ replace constant
            .optionalAttr( "aria-disabled", state.disabled ? "true" : null ) // ++ replace constant
            .optionalAttr( "aria-expanded", state.hasChildren === false ? null : state.expanded ? "true" : "false" ) // ++ replace constant
            .markup( ">" )
            .content( nodeAdapter.getLabel( node ) )
            .markup( " <span class='job'>") // ++ add span for job
            .content( node.job ) // ++
            .markup( "</span></" + elementName + ">" ); // ++ close the span
    };
    return nodeAdapter;
};
return options;
}
```

Most of the above code is similar to the previous or copied from the treeView widget. The traverse function splits the tooltip in to 3 parts. The nodeAdapter lines that were modified are marked with // ++. The most intersting change is adding the span and job.

Add another CSS rule such as:

```
.a-TreeView-label .job { text-transform: lowercase; font-style: italic; }
```

This should do. Change the css rule on the last line to your needs to control the behaviour.